# Some multiple value with same name field working and some field is not working

Tags: forms

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[]"/>
</div>
<div class="column">
<select name="break[]" onchange="count_time('total',this);">
<option value=""> -Select City- </option>
<option>.15</option>
<option>.10</option>
<option>.05</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="column">
<input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" readonly="readonly">
<input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[]"/>
</div>
<div class="column">
<select name="break[]" onchange="count_time('total',this);">
<option value=""> -Select City- </option>
<option>.15</option>
<option>.10</option>
<option>.05</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="column">
<input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" readonly="readonly">
<input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total">
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

this is my first post.There are many field in my form.when i submit the form i got the datepicker value accordingly but i can not get the 2 total field value but when i see in the browser i can see there is 2 identical value in those field.

Comment: You have 4 `total` fields, not 2. They should end up in an array in the server code.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems ok, though I am not quite sure what is setting the value for the total fields, since they do not have a default value and you didn't paste the code that is supposed to calculate the total. My best guess is that you might have a problem with that piece of code and not with the form code itself.

Here is a minimized piece of php code that only uses the total fields, which seems to work just fine. I've added default values to the fields so that you'll be able to see that it is indeed working properly.

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" readonly="readonly" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" readonly="readonly" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total" value="4">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Printing the post result I get the following array of total values:

```
Array ( [total] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [submit] => submit )
```

I you'll post the Javascript code that sets the total values I'll be more than happy to take a look at it as well.